# Specify the order in which Maven plugins' executions run

Tags: java, maven

I'm using the `copy-rename-maven-plugin` during the `package` phase to first copy the `jar` that I just generated to another directory, then using `launch4j-maven-plugin` I'm generating `exe`s that wrap the `jar` and then I need to rename one of the `exe`s (to `scr`), so, I'm using `copy-rename-maven-plugin` again.

The problem is that all `copy-rename-maven-plugin` executions are run together, before `launch4j-maven-plugin`, so, the second execution fails.

How do define the order of executions? I'm happy creating more phases if that's what's necessary, but creating a Maven plugin seemed a bit of an overkill.

A simplified example of what's going with my `pom.xml` would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>tech.projecx</groupId>
    <artifactId>projecx</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.coderplus.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>copy-rename-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution> <!-- Copy the just-built projecx jar to targte/win32/jars -->
                        <id>copy-jar-for-exe</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar</sourceFile>
                            <destinationFile>${project.build.directory}/win32/jars/${project.build.finalName}.jar
                            </destinationFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin> <!-- Make the exes -->
                <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.21</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution> <!-- Make the screensaver exe -->
                        <id>wrap-screensaver-as-exe</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>launch4j</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <headerType>gui</headerType>
                            <outfile>${project.build.directory}\win32\${screensaverExe}.exe</outfile>
                            <jar>jars\${project.build.finalName}.jar</jar>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.coderplus.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>copy-rename-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution> <!-- Copy the screensaver from the exe to the proper scr -->
                        <id>rename-screensaver-to-scr</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>rename</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceFile>${project.build.directory}/win32/${screensaverExe}.exe</sourceFile>
                            <destinationFile>${project.build.directory}/win32/${screensaverExe}.scr</destinationFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The order in which executions need to run is this:

1. `copy-jar-for-exe`
2. `wrap-screensaver-as-exe`
3. `rename-screensaver-to-scr`

Any other order doesn't work, but because, I think, `copy-jar-for-exe` and `renamer-screensaver-to-scr` are executions from the same plugin, Maven runs it like this:

1. `copy-jar-for-exe`
2. `rename-screensaver-to-scr`
3. `wrap-screensaver-as-exe`

so, it fails.

Comment: have you tried binding the executions to different phases before or after the test phase?

Comment: @GeraldMücke: no, because I don't see any appropriate phase to do that. There's only one phase, from the Maven set of built in phases, that's appropriate for all of these tasks, and that is `package`. I don't want any of the packaging happening on the CI, which runs the `test` phase.

Comment: hm, I probably still don't get what you like to achieve and how, maybe it would help to see what you've done so far in you pom.xml and what you intend to achieve on a conceptual level (step-by-step), Could you add that to the question?

Comment: @GeraldMücke sure, just a moment.

Comment: @GeraldMücke: done, does it make sense now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run the `copy-jar-for-exe` in the prepare-package phase. I beleive you could define both executions in the same plugin configuration but declare the plugin after the launch4j plugin.

Basic idea is, the plugins with executions in the same phase are executed in the order of appearance in the pom. If you bind a single execution to another (earlier) phase, it should be executed before.

I haven't tested this, but I think it should work

```
<plugin> 
    <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.21</version>
    <executions>
        <execution> <!-- Make the screensaver exe -->
            <id>wrap-screensaver-as-exe</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>launch4j</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <headerType>gui</headerType>
                <outfile>${project.build.directory}\win32\${screensaverExe}.exe</outfile>
                <jar>jars\${project.build.finalName}.jar</jar>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.coderplus.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>copy-rename-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution> 
            <id>copy-jar-for-exe</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase> <!-- run this execution before package phase -->
            <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sourceFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar</sourceFile>
                <destinationFile>${project.build.directory}/win32/jars/${project.build.finalName}.jar
                </destinationFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution> 
            <id>rename-screensaver-to-scr</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>rename</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sourceFile>${project.build.directory}/win32/${screensaverExe}.exe</sourceFile>
                <destinationFile>${project.build.directory}/win32/${screensaverExe}.scr</destinationFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```